# How can I change the global value when clicked a button jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I face a challenge that I need to change the global value. See code below, whenever user click the #first, it will count the times and store on the server side. However, I want to achieve that if I click the second, the global value become 1. Therefore, when I clicked #first again, it start from 1 again. How can I achieve that, appreciate?

```js
var count=1;//global value

$('#first').on('click',function(){ 
     count++   
});

$('#second').on('click',function(){ 
     //count--(minus)?? make the global value 
     //become 1 no matter how many time I have clicked #first  
});
```

Comment: forgot ; after count ++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var count=1;//global value

    $('#first').on('click',function(){  
             count++ ;          
    });

    $('#second').on('click',function(){ 
             count=1; //make the global value become 1 no matter how many time I have clicked #first        
    });
```